# In Appsflyer the "number of actions" event is not update when clicked in android device. But working in emulator

Tags: android, appsflyer

In Appsflyer the **number of actions** event is not update when clicked in android device. But working in emulator. What could be the reason? How to fix it? I have added my device in the whitelist. But still my click events do not increase the count in appsflyer dashboard. What am I missing. 
Some events were already added. They are working fine. On particular event that I added is not posting any updates in appsflyer.

```
eventValue.put("af_device_id", <hidden text>);
eventValue.put(AFInAppEventParameterName.CONTENT, <hidden text>);
eventValue.put(AFInAppEventParameterName.CONTENT_ID, <hidden text>);
eventValue.put("af_variant_id", <hidden text>);
eventValue.put(AFInAppEventParameterName.CURRENCY, <hidden text>);
eventValue.put(AFInAppEventParameterName.PRICE, <hidden text>);
eventValue.put(AFInAppEventParameterName.CONTENT_TYPE, <hidden text>);
eventValue.put("af_user_phone", <hidden text>);
eventValue.put("af_user_name", <hidden text>);
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().trackEvent(context, "af_recommendations_click", eventValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong data range. So the events didn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without seeing debug logs, but if the event is dispatched from one device (emulator) and not the other (android device), it might be a connectivity issue.

You can turn on AppsFlyer SDK debug logs using the following API:
`AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().setDebugLog(true);`

This article has some useful pointers on debug logs and behaviour: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001559405-Testing-AppsFlyer-SDK-integration#debugging

If this does not help solve the issue, I would recommend opening a ticket to AppsFlyer Support: support@appsflyer.com (with the SDK debug logs you have collected from the device)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It was my mistake. I had the wrong date range. So it didn't show up in the appsflyer

Comment: Where needs to put `AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().setDebugLog(true)` ?